# Julia : How to detect whether a given 2D array has missing columns?

Tags: matrix, julia

Let

```
a = [1 missing;2 missing]
```

The second column contains all *missing* elements.

How to check whether a column contains all *missing* elements?

I tried

```
all(i -> missing == i,a)
a[:,2] .== missing
```

but not succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you want to check a specific column, then do:

```
julia> all(ismissing, view(a, :, 2))
true
```

if you want to check all columns then do:

```
julia> all.(ismissing, eachcol(a))
2-element BitVector:
 0
 1
```

Comment: You really rocks!!